# Vuex mutation won't update state?

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I have a list of objects of blocks, with properties, and id.

The classic way to remove the item from the array won't help me to remove an item, can you tell me why?

Run action:

```
this.$store.dispatch("removeBlockFromList", id); //id is here!
```

action:

```
removeBlockFromList({ commit }, id) {
 commit("REMOVE_BLOCK_FROM_LIST", id) // id is here!
}
```

Mutation:

```
REMOVE_BLOCK_FROM_LIST(state, id) { //id is here
            state.blockList = state.blockList.filter(item => {
                return item.id === id; //connection is here too, true
            }).shift();
        }
```

I have tried to rewrite the array to an empty array like:

```
state.blockList = [];
```

Again not working...

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem . The question cannot be answered in general. It works the way you did it

Comment: It should work.`state.blockList = state.blockList.filter(x=> x.id !== id)`. I cannot comprehend the `shift()` method.

Comment: if you want to filter out id i.e remove from block of list. The condition has to be reversed `item.id !== id` like so . this will filter out that specific id and return your list.